# what are the syntax of connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, debian

My question is about Mysql connection through Debian  .I am working on debian8 machine . I want to connect mysql database . If i am connecting with syntax without space between flag u and username and password and hostaname  like this mysql -uusername -ppassword -hhostname i am able to connect , but if i am connecting like mysql -u username -p password . I am getting this error ....ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'. the second syntax is trying to connect through socket , but what first is doing . and how can be the socket issue be resolved ?

Comment: MySQL installed on local machine or external IP ?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter

```
--type-your-password
```

[image]This should work